# tweet post Image with {"errors":[{"code":189,"message":"Error creating status."}]}

Tags: php, json, image, twitter

I'm trying to publish tweet on twitter with image and a link to my site
I get the following error:

```
{"errors": [{"code": 189, "message": ". Error creating status"}]}
```

I tried with twitter api:
with  update.json
the tweet is published but no picture.
and

update_with_media.json

I get error

this is the code I use:

```
require '../tmhOAuth.php';
require '../tmhUtilities.php';
 $tmhOAuth = new tmhOAuth(array(
   'consumer_key'    => 'xxxxxxxxxx',
   'consumer_secret' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx',
   'user_token'      => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    'user_secret'     => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
     ));

       // we're using a hardcoded image path here. You can easily replace                  this with an uploaded image-see images.php example)
      // 'image = "@{$_FILES['image']['tmp_name']};type={$_FILES['image'] ['type']};filename={$_FILES['image']['name']}",

     $picimg="img.jpg";

     $code = $tmhOAuth->request('POST',             'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update_with_media.json',

     array(
      'media[]'  => "@{$picimg}",
      'status'   => "status"
      ),
     true, // use auth
      true  // multipart
      );

  if ($code == 200) {
        tmhUtilities::pr(json_decode($tmhOAuth->response['response']));
   } else {
       tmhUtilities::pr($tmhOAuth->response['response']);
          }
```

I searched a lot on google but not served me anything.
I do not understand what's going on

Answer (score 0):

It was poorly cast the image url and more stuff.
I have made an example of different api in my local.
I used APIs
https://github.com/themattharris/tmhOAuth

I've also installed composer for dependencies.
installing dependencies twitter api.

Well the most important thing is:
this piece of code:

```
  $picimg="img.jpg";
  array(
  'media[]'  => "@{$picimg}",
  'status'   => "status"
  )
```

this is wrong.
but this above is good

```
$image = __DIR__.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR .'..' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'fotos'.         DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'foto1.jpg';
```

DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR is used instead of backslash, and this is very important if not the error response would be 189

```
$name  = basename($image);
$status = "Picture time";
$media = "@{$image};type=image/jpg;filename={$name}";
```

media must be represented well in this format, not only url string.

```
  // we set the type and filename are set here as well
    $params = array(
   'media[]' => $media,
   'status'  => $status
 );
```

This is working AMIGOS